# DataTable hide rows correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, row

I have much experience with javascript and I have a big problem to solve.

How do I hide some row lines correctly?

I like it when the line was hidden the table to be "reset" with only the visible lines, showing the paging and the visible lines usually.

```
var tableList = $('#listaJogadores').DataTable();
var tabela = document.getElementById('listaJogadores');

$(document).on("click",".searchButton" ,function(){

  for (var i = 1; i < tabela.rows.length; i++) {
     var divPosicao = tabela.rows[i].cells[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML;
     var divIdJogador = tabela.rows[i].cells[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[1].innerHTML;

      if (divPosicao != posicaoLista){
        tabela.rows[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
   }
});
```

[Problem image here](http://s10.postimg.org/4apwkqljd/tabela_1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

add row contents inside a `<div>` then hide the div